# How do I write a macro that scans a lookup table stored in a SAS data set?

Tags: macros, sas

I have a very short (<20 rows) data set that looks like:

```
Effective_Date  Pct
--------------  ---
01JAN2000       50%
...
11FEB2014       55%
13JUL2014       65%
```

I'd like to write a macro which takes a date, `Eval_Date` and returns the `Pct` which was effective on that date. To be clear, I know that this can be done with some kind of `PROC SQL` construction, but I want to write a function-style macro that can be used in the data step.

For example, `%pct('12jul2014'd)` should evaluate to `55%`.

Comment: I have a feeling you have misapprehensions as to how SAS works.  There is no 'in memory lookup' in this context; data stored in datasets is stored on disk, always, unless (in rare cases) you've defined a library in memory - but that's very rarely done.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to do this function-style, ie, it could be called in a data step without terminating the data step?

Comment: I'm positive that I don't understand how SAS works, but: there is certainly in-memory lookup using `_temporary_` arrays.

I do mean function-style, exactly like that.

Comment: You can load the dataset and do any number of things in memory, but those things are still loading from disk initially. I will explain some options when I am on a pc again. Formats are a good place to start though, that's the simplest option.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your source dataset is `effpct` and pct is numeric, formatted as `percent.`, use it to create a format containing every day and the effective percent:

```
/* Merge without a by statement, using firstobs=2 to do a look-ahead join to 
   determine the 'effective to' date */

data pct_fmt ;
  retain fmtname 'EFFPCT' type 'N' ;
  merge effpct
        effpct (firstobs=2 keep=effective_date rename=(effective_date=to_date)) ;

  if missing(to_date) then to_date = date() ; /* Take last record up to current date */

  do start = effective_date to (to_date - 1) ;
    label = pct ;
    output ;
  end ;
run ;
/* 'Compile' the format */
proc format cntlin=pct_fmt ; run ;

/* Abstract put(var,format) into a function-style macro */
%MACRO PCT(DT) ;
  put(&DT,EFFPCT.) ;
%MEND ;

/* Then use it in a datastep... */
data want ;
  input date date9. ;
  eff_pct = %PCT(date) ;
  format eff_pct percent9. ;
datalines ;
01JAN2000
13FEB2014
20JUL2014
;
run ;
```

Or alternatively, use `%SYSFUNC` and `putn` to be able to convert a date to percent outside of a datastep, e.g. in a `title` statement :

```
%MACRO PCT2(DT) ;
  %SYSFUNC(putn(%SYSFUNC(putn(&DT,EFFPCT.)),percent.))
%MEND ;

title "The effective pct on 09JUL2013 was %PCT2('09jul2013'd)" ;
```

Comment: The only thing i'd add is to add a row for `hlo='o'`, or the 'other' option, which will return a value when the listed value is not found.  You also ought to not subtract one, but instead use the option to use up-to-and-not-including (in a value statement, `0<-100` means the range from 0 to 100 but not including the value of 0) since it is possible for dates to have decimal portions if brought in from other DBMSs (although that's not really a big deal in general).

Comment: Thanks. That's very interesting, and I'll now go study SAS formats, which are clearly much more powerful (and essential) than I'd thought. (I have been using SAS for less than a week.)

Comment: I found this document from SAS helpful in understanding the use of a format to do this: http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/068-2007.pdf